# PHP Link Shortener

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

Zack here.. I've recently run into a spot of trouble with my URL Shortener.. Can you check the below code for errors? Thanks so much!

```
    <?php 
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","pretzel_main","00WXE5fMWtaVd6Dd","pretzel");
    function code($string_length = 3) {
        $permissible_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $char_length = strlen($permissible_characters);
        $random = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++) {
            $random .= $permissible_characters[rand(0, $char_length - 1)];
        }
        return $random;
    }
    if (substr($_POST['long'], 0, 7) == http://) {
        $url = $_POST['long'];
    } elseif (substr($_POST['long'], 0, 8) == https://) {
        $url = $_POST['long'];
    } else {
        $url = "http://".$_POST['long'];
    }
    $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO links VALUES('',?,?)");
    $result->bind_param("ss",$url, $title);
    $result->execute();
    $title = $code();
?>
```

Good luck, and Thanks in advance!
- Zack

Comment: `){]$`  => this is not valid... turn on your error report

Comment: @ZDavies no, it's gone with you edit, so a typo maybe. but still this `$code();` not good

Comment: **What** trouble are you running into? Specific errors.

Comment: @Blag Why isn't it Blag?

Comment: @ZDavies cause `$code();` mean this `$code = 'functionName'; {$code}(); /*same as*/ functionName();` AKA you don't need the`$` before your function call I think : `$title = code();`

Comment: @ZDavies did you tried my new answer?

Comment: @ZDavies since you are not interested in checking code, i am deleting y code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 <?php 
    $db = new mysqli("localhost","pretzel_main","00WXE5fMWtaVd6Dd","pretzel");
    function code($string_length = 3) {
        $permissible_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        $char_length = strlen($permissible_characters);
        $random = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $string_length; $i++) {
            $random .= $permissible_characters[rand(0, $char_length - 1)];
        }
        return $random;
    }
    if (substr($_POST['long'], 0, 7) == "http://") {
        $url = $_POST['long'];
    } elseif (substr($_POST['long'], 0, 8) == "https://") {
        $url = $_POST['long'];
    } else {
        $url = "http://".$_POST['long'];
    }
    $result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO links VALUES('ss','$url','$title')");
    $result->execute();
    $title = code(); // no need of $ sign here
?>
```

Comment: no, just no, so remove your post before you get a bunch of -1 ; they are way more error in the code than what you changed

Comment: Awesome! Just got one more error though.. Can you help?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in /home/etcl/public_html/9ui/index.php on line 43